# How can I write a "fluent" datetime value?

Tags: c#, datetime

How do I Write C# code that will allow to compile the following code :

```
var date = 8.September(2013); // Generates a DateTime for the 8th of September 2013
```

Comment: I wouldn't want to code like that. However, I think it's a interesting concept - so hopefully the title changes will get some (non-negative) votes.

Comment: why all the downvoting?

Comment: This question shows no research effort whatsoever. -1.

Comment: I downvoted, not because the suggested fluent interface is so bad, but because the question was asked in a brusque manner without context, previous research or effort.

Comment: @user414076: How would you have researched this? Without any knowledge of extension methods, how would you know what to look for?

Comment: question seems clear enough, and all the answers seem to address the question straightforwardly enough

Comment: @JonSkeet, we don't know he has no knowledge of extension methods. We shouldn't spoon feed every ridiculous request.

Comment: @KeithNicholas: Because most programmers are terrified of anything new.  Well, that and the example breaks (from a cursory, hipshot glance) about 5 different typing rules in C#.

Comment: @user414076: True, we don't *know* that he doesn't - but to *assume* there's no research effort seems over the top to me. While there is no evidence of research, I don't think it's the kind of thing that *can* be easily researched.

Comment: @ajax81 not my example, I just came into this question and there was massive downvoting.... and now its gone the other way, massive upvoting!  ahhh... the excitement and drama of stackoverflow :)

Comment: This seems backwards to me. With no knowledge of extension methods, the syntax proposed is simply invalid C#. Did the OP see this syntax, or a similar one, and want to know how it is implemented? If that were the question, I don't think there would have been as many downvotes.

Comment: @JonSkeet: A Google search for "c# add methods to int" (which would be the only way to do this, sans extension methods) brings up the MSDN page on extension methods as the very first result.

Comment: @KeithNicholas: author corrected (thanks).  I will add that I'm in the "for" camp here.  Anybody that likes jQuery chaining should appreciate what this example brings to the table.  +1 from this guy!

Comment: @cHao: I suspect it's easier to think of that as a search term when you already know the answer, though.

Comment: +1 With new title I think this question (and especially answers) provide good information on the topic for future readers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use an extension method:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static DateTime September(this int day, int year)
    {
        return new DateTime(year, 9, day);
    }
}
```

However, this is generally bad practice, and I'd recommend against this kind of thing, especially for something as trivial as this—is `new DateTime(2013, 9, 8)` really so much more difficult than `8.September(2013)`? There may be times where this kind of trick can be useful or fun for practice, but it should be used sparingly.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It answers the question perfectly. +1.

Comment: @Sparko where do you live?

Comment: Do we *really* want to reward such low effort? Besides, you could stand to do some day and year validations.

Comment: @alexn maybe he lives in Java land ;).  @user414076 the `DateTime` constructor will perform the same validation that it would had the OP simply invoked it directly.

Comment: @Sparko - This isn't javascript.

Comment: @alexn I believe a previous edit of this answer said 2 instead of 9. Or that was a different answer that is now deleted.

Comment: @keaton_fu - Well even if it did the concept is fundamentally a correct answer. Is it really worth a DV rather than a comment?

Comment: @Sparko I admit, I fat-fingered this when I was first typing it up (thinking 2nd parameter, ended up typing 2), but I corrected it immediately.

Comment: Correct, the original edit had a value of 2 for the month, instead of 9. @MartinSmith Not sure how this would relate to Javascript?

Comment: This is technically correct. However, this is not good C# style (for production); it would be useful to explain this. I could easily see how someone coming from e.g. Ruby could want to do this, but it goes against convention.

Comment: @Martin I was just hoping to prevent a situation where two people start fighting for no good reason because of a misunderstanding (who I am kidding, this is the internet). For example you assumed when he said incorrect month, it was from the perspective of month-indexing, and not pointing out a typo.

Comment: @Sparko - I only saw the `9` version. In javascript with its zero based months `new Date(2013,9,8)` is October. I thought that might be the reason for the comment.

Answer (score 14):

I would recommend against this, as it strikes me as very poor style.  That said, if you *really* want to do this statically, you would need to define twelve different extension methods (one for each month name) like so:

```
public static class DateConstructionExtensions
{
    public static DateTime January(this int day, int year)
    {
        return new DateTime(year, /* month: */1, day);
    }

    // equivalent methods for February, March, etc...
}
```

Comment: I've actually found this to be very usable when writing tests - they end up being very easy to read. I wouldn't use it for non-test code though.

Comment: Fair enough, Jon :).  As long as it isn't polluting the public namespaces.

Comment: Oh absolutely - I would only put it in a namespace specifically for "making test data easier to read" extension methods. (I'd also make it return a Noda Time `LocalDate` of course ;)

Comment: I cannot describe how tempted I am to start using this.

Comment: @JonSkeet - The idea of code just to make tests more readable strikes me as redundant; now you need unit tests to prove the code you only use for unit tests will work in your unit tests. I'd prefer something more useful outside the test libs, like an "AsDate" extension for strings wrapping DateTime.Parse(). "8 September 2013".AsDate() is just as readable, and useful anywhere you need to do string-to-date parsing, not just for setting up tests.

Comment: @KeithS: I definitely don't see that as *nearly* as readable - and it's easier to get wrong when writing the test, as typos won't be spotted until you *run* the test. I have absolutely no problems with writing code just to help with testing - indeed in Noda Time we have a whole separate assembly for that purpose. The more conveniently you can write data for tests, the better.

Answer (score 8):

You could do this via extensions:

```
public static DateTime September(this int day, int year) {
    return new DateTime(year, 9, day);
}
```

Of course, you'd need 12 such extensions, one for each month.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can have the implementation like this:

```
public partial interface IMonth {
    int Number {
        get;
    }
}

public partial class February: IMonth {
    public int Number {
        get {
            return 2;
        }
    }
}

public static partial class Extensions {
    public static DateTime OfMonth<T>(this int day, int year) 
            where T: IMonth, new() {
        var month=new T();
        var daysInMonth=DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month.Number);

        if(1>day||day>daysInMonth)
            throw new ArgumentException();

        return new DateTime(year, month.Number, day);
    }
}
```

For the reason I declare months as classes, is because months might have different names in different cultures. You might want to provide different aliases for them.

Then, for the reason there's `IMonth`, is a contract that months must implement it. The extension method has the constraint `new()` is for avoiding `IMonth` itself or an abstract class be used.

This implementation also checks for the valid day number.

And you can assign the variable `date` as:

```
var date=(28).OfMonth<February>(2013);
```

Make sense?